# Extract a field from neo4j.Record class

Tags: java, neo4j, record

I have a Record and I want to extract the field "first_name" that is inside the record as below:

[image]

I tried

```
String aaa = record.values().get(0).get("adapted").get("properties").get("firstName").toString();
```

but it didn't work. Doing a more in depth debug I found out that the .get("adapted") is not working as it should and returns NULL

Comment: Please don't post images, and explain what "didn't work" means.

Comment: @tgdavies why not posting images? I think this is the best way to explain what I have to achieve, via image it is easy to understand the path. I explained better the "didn't work"

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: `adapted` is a field on the `NodeValue` class. The method `get(String)` is for reading the value of a property with a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer my self, since adapted is a Node and properties is a Map, I had to do

```
String aaa = record.values().get(i).asMap().get("firstName");
```